# Не удаётся установить mongodump, mongodb и другие утилиты, связанные с mongo на debian (внутри контейнера)

Tags: debian, mongodb, docker, резервное-копирование

Работаю на ubuntu18.04. По долгу службы потребовалось воспользоваться утилитой `mongodump` внутри контейнера. При этом, я воспользовался стандартным контейнером [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python). В частности: `3.7.5-stretch, 3.7-stretch`. Но аналогичная проблема возникает и для любого другого контейнера на Debian. Для меня представляет интерес корректная работа `mongodump`.

**Мои действия по воспроизведению ошибки**

Если Вы проделаете то, что описано [тут](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#install-mongodb-community-edition), то ничего не получите:

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

При этом, я делал следующее:

```
docker run -it python:3.7.2-slim-stretch /bin/bash

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -

apt-get install gnupg

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

apt-get update

apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Вы также можете попробовать установить только лишь `mongo-tools`. Но скорее всего Вы получите неработающую версию `mongodump`. В этом случае, Вы не сможете корректно производить операцию по созданию бэкапов.

Как и в случае выше, я делаю следующее:

1. Захожу внутрь контейнера

.

```
docker run -it python:3.7.2-slim-stretch /bin/bash
```

2. Обновляю `apt`

.

```
apt update
```

2. Устанавливаю ряд пакетов, которые нужны мне для работы и для `mongo`:

.

```
apt install procps wget gnupg2 apt-transport-https
```

3. Добавляю исходники монги:

.

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -
```

4. Обновляю

.

apt update

5. Пробую установить `mongodump`:

.

```
apt-get install -y mongo-tools
```

Установка проходит успешно. Но, увы, сделать дамп я не могу:

.

```
mongodump --host 1.2.3.4 --port 27017 -d "x-x" -o xxx
```

> 2019-10-21T14:18:13.127+0000    writing x-x.zzzz to 
>   2019-10-21T14:18:13.132+0000    Failed: error reading collection:
>   Failed to parse: { find: "zzzz", skip: 0, snapshot: true,
>   $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "x-x" }.
>   Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.

Вы также можете получить другого толка ошибку, если сделаете:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb://abs:cbs@1.2.3.4: -o xxx
```

> ```
> 2019-10-21T14:21:00.310+0000    error parsing command line options: unknown option "uri"
> 2019-10-21T14:21:00.310+0000    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
> ```

К сожалению, ошибки ни о чём не говорят и только вводят в заблуждение.

Comment: Синтаксис mongodump некорректный. должно быть так: mongodump --uri="mongodb://abs:cbs@1.2.3.4:" -o xxx. Подробнее тут: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#syntax

Comment: @balamutik Это неважно. Можно и так, и так. Сейчас опубликую ответ и посмотрите, где собака зарыта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, внимательно посмотрим на [репу](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#install-mongodb-community-edition). Рассмотрим п.2.

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

Если зайти по адресу http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian, то легко увидеть, что структура каталогов отличается от той, что указана в строке выше. Правильная строка следующая:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-enterprise/4.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

Кроме того, Вам следует заметить, что mongodump/mongorestore входят в состав самой mongodb, кажется, начиная с версии 4.0 (либо, с 4.2). В таком случае, Вам нужно установить только лишь саму монгу, без всех дополнительных пакетов, которые указаны в ссылках.

Второе замечание. Строка в впоросе, находится в доменной зоне `.com`, а по ссылке `.org`. Таким образом, поправив .com -> .org, всё будет собираться. Именно это замечание является ключевым.

Итоговое решение. Заходим в контейнер:

```
docker run -it python:3.7.2-slim-stretch /bin/bash
```

Выполняем:

```
apt update


apt install procps wget gnupg2 apt-transport-https

wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -

 echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

apt update

apt install  mongodb-org=4.2.1 mongodb-org-server=4.2.1 mongodb-org-shell=4.2.1 mongodb-org-mongos=4.2.1 mongodb-org-tools=4.2.1
```

Далее, `mongodump` работает, как указано в вопросе.